# How do I switch my ReSharper license in VS 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resharper, jetbrains-ide

I'm a contractor and I just switched companies with which I'm working.  They hand out to their devs ReSharper licenses.  The problem is, I already have a personal ReSharper license that's expiring in a few months and since I'm in the middle of the setup and onboarding process, I'd like to go ahead and switch my JetBrains license details.

Other than possibly uninstalling and reinstalling ReSharper, I can't figure out, find or even Google a way to switch licenses.  Is there a way that I can simply input a new license key in ReSharper in VS or, maybe, pass in a parameter to an app with the updated details?

I can do a reinstall if I need to but I (and others I'm sure) would rather avoid this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In he VS2017 menu, you see an entry `Resharper`, click on it and next `Help`->`License Information ...`

[image]

Here you can remove the old license and add the new one.

Comment: Easy enough, once you know how to do it.  I knew there had to be a way.